# Caching response from Retrofit

Tags: android, json, caching, retrofit

I do apologize in advance as I know the question already exist but I wanted to find out a easier method or a guide to explain it thoroughly.

I am using Retrofit to obtain a response from Reddit's website in Json. I want to cache the response for the application to be used in the offline mode. I also want to update the response if there are new items in the response or Json.

Can you please guide me in the right direction as I've never worked with caching before.

Comment: Retrofit does not support caching.
http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-volley-vs-retrofit-better-approach/

Comment: This might be helpful https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-activate-response-caching-etag-last-modified

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do so, at least for me, is to make a model pojo class, and put the response that was given in an object of the class. About the caching, I'm using [hawk](https://github.com/orhanobut/hawk) which is a simple key - value storage that is proven to be easy to use and is working great as it puts the data in applications storage and stays there even if you uninstall and reinstall the app.

About the updating part, you have to get the response anyway in order to see if it is the same or not, so why not simple override the old one, that way you will always have the latest one.

For that matter I'm using [evernote job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job), which works great with RxJava (if you are using), it works excellent with the POST method and has attributes like `.setPeriodic(TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1))` where you put the time in which a job should be ran (this is good for caching every x minutes), and also `.setUpdateCurrent(true)` that will update the current response if needed.

Just try looking in the documentation of these two libraries, and maybe you will find them helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For caching response use `OkHttpClient` in Retrofit builder.

```
int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MB  
Cache cache = new Cache(getCacheDir(), cacheSize);

OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .cache(cache)
        .build();

Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2:3000/")
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
```

The Retrofit instance above will cache all responses until it reached the 10 MB maximum. After it exceeded the cache disk limit, it'll clean up the oldest entries.

For more detail: [Retrofit response caching](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-activate-response-caching-etag-last-modified)